# python 3.4 windows 8.1 unable to create file in C:\

Tags: python, windows-8.1

I'm trying to run a script in python3.4 & windows 8 .

It worked well with windows 7 but now, in windows 8.1 it can´t write a file in C: , may be access denied.
If I change the directory, for example User/xxx it works, but I don´t know how to do to 'write' in C:

```
with open('C:/xxxx.csv', 'r') as csvfile:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\Scripts_jmab\csv_to_shp.py", line     12, in <module>
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(a,filename)    
  File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 188, in urlretrieve
    tfp = open(filename, 'wb')
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'C:/xxxxx.csv'
```

thanks

Comment: can you create a file in ``C:\`` outside of Python? If you can't do it there, you won't be able to through Python...

Comment: Hi I can create a folder but not a file

Comment: I think win 8.1 doesn't let you create a file directly in C:

Answer (score 0):

Due to security settings in Windows, users are not allowed to create files in the root `C:\` folder, as some important system files reside there that could be attacked by viruses. While it is possible to disable this feature, the easiest (and safest) solution is to create a directory for your programs to put their output files in. `C:\TEMP` is a good location (you can create it if it doesn't already exist), or you can make another folder named according to your own choosing.

Comment: thanks. It´s the thing I´ll do. Then I must create the script for win 7 and a different one for win8.

Comment: @kamome - writing to ``C:\`` is generally a bad idea on any version of Windows, so I'd suggest using a temp directory for both.